# how to execute stored procedures using jmeter and get results

Tags: testing, stored-procedures, jdbc, jmeter

I have a database that contain table1.
DB got stored procedure that returns a table as result.
Now how do i use jmeter to hit the store procedure and get the results on to jmeter and store it in a file.

suppose result table would have several rows and 3 columns.
how to store each column in separate file
eg:
column 1 into file1.csv
column 2 into file2.csv
column 3 into file3.csv

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure your [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) as follows

   - Query Type: `Callable Statement`
   - Query: your SP name
   - Result variable name: `result`
   - Handle Result Set: `Store as Object`

     [image]
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request and put hte following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.getObject('result').each { row ->
       row.values().eachWithIndex { def entry, int i ->
           new File('file_' + (i + 1) + '.csv') << entry << System.getProperty('line.separator')
       }
   }
   ```

That's it, you will have files like:

- `file1.csv`
- `file2.csv`
- etc.

generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation containing the values from respective columns of the query result.

Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more detailed information on the above approach if needed.